# Windows Phone 8.1 app text scale

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, autoscaling

I have a problem with text scale in my Windows Phone 8.1 app. When I run app on device my labels is bigger than should be and not fits to screen (cutting ends). I had no such problems in the past with Windows Phone 8.0 apps. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you want to achieve? Are you looking for *TextWrapping* behavior, or do you have a problem with the *TextScaling* from the Ease of Access settings?

Comment: The problem is that in real device text appears bigger than in simulator

Comment: Devices habe different scale factors (and there are different emulators to choose, with different resolutions. It's not a static resolution for all devices.

Comment: In 8.1 is something different, because in 8.0 I didn't had such problems. My app is not universal.

Comment: Are you using Silverlight or Phone Store App? Yes there are differences. For example in 8.1 you can go to Settings -> Ease of Access and set a System wide text scale factor.
Also, in 8.1 Apps no longer just have a fixed resolution that gets scaled up (old was 800*480), but have a device dependent scale factor and aspect ratio. So yes, it is different since 8.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the solution. It was all about my settings in device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although late reply, you can use `IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"` property to override effect of ease of access setting.